# Reciting the Quran in English

Tags: sharia, quran, salat, hadith-interpretation, quran-recitation

*Let me start from introducing myself,*
I am an 18-year-old boy and have been thinking like crazy about this, but this is my conclusion to ask someone, because I have no idea.

I was on a website reading about how hell and paradise is like *OR* levels in heaven, so I have read this sentence:

> Whoever recites all of the Qur’an, will reach the highest degree of Paradise in the Hereafter, and whoever recites part of it will reach a level commensurate with that, and the limit of his reward will match the limit of his reading.

I do not know Arabic; I always been taught to read the Qur'an in a way I could understand it, so I chose English. Because it's important to know and read the message sent down to us. I don't know if the Qur'an can be recited in English, but if it is, that's really good, because I read it every day.

I recently just got more into Islam. I was born an Muslim my whole life, but I never valued my religion before but watching Islamic videos and reading helped a lot. That's when I realized my mistake of forgetting Allah, but anyway I am working hard for paradise and insha'Allah I will be granted paradise. I don't want any part of hell. It's too bad, so my question is:

Can the Qur'an be recited in English, and is it still a good deed that I am reading it?

Answer (score 2):

*Actually there are two things,*
You can recite Qur'an in any language for understanding it and it will be good deed that you want to understand Qur'an in your own language so either you recite it in Arabic or English, doesn't matter because you are still reciting Qur'an.

*But,* the nature of every person is to seek for bigger rewards so if you are having difficulties reciting Qur'an in Arabic then you are getting double rewards.

> One who is skilled in the Qur'an is associated with the noble, upright recording angels, **and he who falters when he recites the Qur'an and finds it difficult for him will have a double reward.** *[Sunan Abi Dawud 1454 - Book 8, Hadith 39](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/8/39)*

*So* it is important for you to at least learn the basics of Arabic so that you can recite Qur'an in Arabic language and for then you can read its translation to understand the Qur'an.

Answer (score -1):

Aslamualikum
May Allah SWT shower his blessing upon other muslim brothers of world.
Firstly I like ur way towards QURAN.
Dear if u recite quran in this world and will follow the the teachings of Prophet Muhmmud SAW ,THEN u r sucessful.
Now as per ur statement u said I am facing problems in reciting quran in Arabic language.
Dear I will give u a book were u can easily recite quran in arabic language.
Also If our brothers and sisters need any kind of help regarding islam then treat me as ur slave for Islam.
please contact me on shahidbutt88@gmail.com

Comment: Please use proper English. *You are*, not *u r*.

Answer (score -2):

Allah's language is Arabic, even though He understands all. Just like we offer Salaah in Arabic, we are supposed to recite the Quran in Arabic too. Yes to understand it, its best recite in the language you know most, but then why did Allah give us the Quran in Arabic and not in any other language???

Comment: Quran is in Arabic, because it was the language of the prophet(PBUH) to whom it was revealed. And we do not know what the language of Allah is. Ref.: islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7791/what-is-the-language-of-allah